# Can't connect ec2 instance via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, jenkins

My security group setting is valid. Port 22 ssh open for everywhere. After assigned elastic ip to my instance and running jenkins on port 8080 I got the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-88-162-240.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

What can i do to fix this ?

(I can't ask this in aws forums with non-premium account)

Comment: A timeout is usually the result of a firewall problem. Configure the appropriate security group for your instance. Also check the local firewall on your server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Actually these are set to security group config
`
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
SSH TCP 22 ::/0
`
I could connect using ssh before assigning elastic ip and running jenkins with same security group.

Comment: Can you ssh to the public (non elastic) IP if it's still assigned to the instance, then restart sshd? Or reboot the instance having assigned the EIP.

Comment: I disassociate elastic IP and tried to connect with public IP after rebooting but still the same issue.

Comment: the problem is about elastic IP because I could ssh before associating elastic IP